# Retrieving the last element of a list in Panda Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this csv file example: (read this as item AAA costs 1000 and item AAA(1) costs 2000)

```
ColumnName
AAA (1000)
AAA (1) (2000)
```

I would like to create a pandas dataframe column of all numbers

ie

```
Column_cost
1000
2000
```

I tried to split this by '(' which returns something like the following (because the second item has '(' in the name:

```
Result 1
Col_1 Col_2 Col_3

AAA 1000) None

AAA   1)  2000)
```

so the numbers are not in the same column

I then tried creating a columns of lists which gives

```
Result 2

ColumnName2

[AAA,1000)]

[AAA,1),2000)]
```

but again, I don't know how to create a column that uses the last element of each list.

I can get it for a particular index, but not for the whole column

```
x = df['ColumnName'].str.split('(',expand=True) gives Result 1 above

x = df['ColumnName'].str.split('(') gives Result 2 above
```

From Result 2, I did the following to get the desired result for one particular cell, but I don't know how to do it for the whole column (I can do this for a small dataset, but not for a large one)

retrieves the list of a particular index, gets the last element of the list, splits it by spaces, and then retrieves the new element of the split list

```
x[0][-1].split()[0]
x[1][-1].split()[0]
```

Comment: @yatu, sorry yes thanks it worked (I think my positive vote didn't count as I am a new user), however, as I am still new to this, I preferred to use the other method as it was a small variation of my code, thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution using [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Column_cost'] = df.ColumnName.str.split('(').str[-1].str.strip(')').astype(int)
```

[out]

```
       ColumnName  Column_cost
0      AAA (1000)         1000
1  AAA (1) (2000)         2000
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, works (somewhow astype(int) didn't work for me so I used apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce') instead, please let me know if you know why, but works now so all good.

Comment: most likely due to non-numeric characters between the last pair of parenthesis. Maybe comma, period or currency symbols..? eg `[, . $]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to match the digits inside the parenthesis, and add `'$'` so it matches only at the end of the string:

```
df.assign(Column_cost = df.ColumnName.str.extract(r'\((\d+)\)$'))

       ColunmName    Column_cost
0      AAA (1000)        1000
1  AAA (1) (2000)        2000
```